# Variable scope in try catch block

Tags: java, variables, scope, try-catch, console-application

I am creating a user interface via command line that will ask for options from 1 - 4 and I want error checking. Only an integer between 1 - 4 is allowed. This is the code I have so far. I want the method to return the userInput integer to another method that will do some stuff with it.

```
package contactmanager;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author andyjohnson
 */
public class UserInterface {

    public static Integer GetInput() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Integer userInput;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the contact manager\nMake a selection below:");
        System.out.println("1)Display Contacts\n2)Add new business contact\n3)Add new personal contact\n4)Quit");
        try {
            Integer userInput = in.nextInt();
            if (userInput < 1 || userInput > 4) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
                UserInterface.GetInput();
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
            UserInterface.GetInput();
        }

        return userInput;

    }

}
```

My return statement is underlined in the IDE and is telling me it isn't initialized. I want to initialize it globally but allow the try statement to change the value. I've tried this.userInput = userInput but I can't figure out where my scope is broken. How do I give the try block global scope? I'm new to java, so anything is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just declare `userInput` variable outside the try-catch block:

```
package contactmanager;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInterface {

    public static Integer GetInput() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the contact manager\nMake a selection below:");
        System.out.println("1)Display Contacts\n2)Add new business contact\n3)Add new personal contact\n4)Quit");
        Integer userInput = null;
        try {
            userInput = in.nextInt();
            if (userInput < 1 || userInput > 4) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
                UserInterface.GetInput();
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
            UserInterface.GetInput();
        }

        return userInput;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try-catch` block has a scope that is dissimilar to just writing code in-line with the rest of the method.

I think the problem you are having is in this line where the variable `userInput` is first declared inside the `try-catch` block:

```
Integer userInput = in.nextInt();
```

The reason why this is an issue:

Consider if the `try-catch` block failed. What would then be returned? The variable `userInput` hasn't even been defined, so Java would have no idea what to return.

The fix is relatively simple. You want to just move it out of the `try-catch` block, like so. That should get rid of your `return` error. I noticed you commented this change out. Why?

But I have an additional suggestion. Why are you calling `UserInterface.GetInput()`? Why not have the method accept the parameter of the valid input and simply don't call it when the data is not formatted appropriately? Do you use it? This would take away the need of a truly global-scoped variable.

Because of how this method is written, it must return an `Integer` of some kind, unless you write it should that the method throws an exception that is caught somewhere downstream.

I tried to make some fixes I think would make the most sense:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer userInput; // Integer representation of user input

try {
    Integer a = in.nextInt(); // if a can be assigned to an Integer this line work
    if (a < 1 || a > 4) {
        // called if the input can be assigned to an Integer and is within the range
        userInput = a;
    }

} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    // otherwise the catch block is called
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection");
}

return userInput;
```

Maybe you want to call `UserInterface.GetInput()` inside the range check? Hope this helps!

**Edit: Using a sentinel flag instead of recalling the method**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a valid Integer.  When done type DONE ");

// this method will keep cycling until the String DONE is typed
// you could make this condition whatever you want
while (!input.hasNext("DONE")) {

    String a = input.next(); // gets the next item from the Scanner

    try {
        Integer b = Integer.parseInt(a); // tries to 'cast' the String to an Integer

        if (b < 1 || b > 4) {
            System.out.println("Input is valid!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input is invalid!");
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to call UserInterface.GetInput() again per the spec. The program needs to give the menu again if input validation fails. I tried this suggestion but it didn't seem to validate the input integer if it was 0 or 5. Entering a string like foo gave me the code in the catch statement. If the try fails validation or the catch executes what is the best way to call the method for the menu again? The spec says this should give the user the menu after input validation failure. I wanted to make the UserInterface method static so it didn't need to be instantiated.

Comment: I have no idea what conditions are outlined in the 'spec' you are looking at. I tested this method and it seems to work for me. I don't understand how `UserInterface.GetInput()` ties into it because you would have already gotten the input.

Comment: I added comments to my original answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: If the input fails I need to ask for the correct input. Is the best way to do that to just call the entire method again, or is there a better way?

Basically, after anything the user does I need it to return to the "Main Menu".

Comment: Oh I get it now. What you are describing is best accomplished through what is called a `sentinel flag`. Hold on, let me edit my post.

Comment: this is pretty cool. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: No problem! Please feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you!